# what is wrong with this DP solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**It's a hackerrank question:** Alice is a kindergarten teacher. She wants to give some candies to the children in her class.  All the children sit in a line ( their positions are fixed), and each  of them has a rating score according to his or her performance in the class.  Alice wants to give at least 1 candy to each child. If two children sit next to each other, then the one with the higher rating must get more candies. Alice wants to save money, so she needs to minimize the total number of candies given to the children.

```
n = int(input())
candies = 1
candy = 1
temp = int(input())
for i in range(1,n):
    temp1 = int(input())
    if (temp1>temp):
        candy = candy + 1        
    else:
        candy = 1

    temp = temp1
    candies = candies+candy 
    print candy

print candies
```

Test array : n  = 10, n elements are [
2
4
2
6
1
7
8
9
2
1]. I am getting 18 as the answer while 19 is the correct answer. I am doing some mistake which I am unable to catch.

This is the link to complete question [https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/candies[]](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/candies)

Comment: In your solution the first two childs receive only one candy, don't they? But the child with score 10 should receive more.

Comment: @Flurin - Ohh crap my mistake. I have updated the question. 10 is number of elements not a part of array.

Comment: ok, then the problem is at the end: `9, 2, 1`. The code would give 3 candies to the child with score 9. Then *one* candy to child with score 2 and *one* to the last child. Child with score 2 should receive 2 candies.

Comment: Also what happens if two childs sit next to each other and have the same score? You would possiby give one multiple candies and the next one only 1. Is that intended?

Comment: @Flurin - my code will give 4 candies to 9. but yes 2[location 9] should get 2 candies while my code is giving it one candy. If the two have same scores then the next one should get candies according to next one to him not necessarily one and that's problem with the code.

Comment: the last 2 should get 2 candies, but in your algorithm, he only gets one.

Comment: You're right. 4 to score=9. I miscounted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this. You are only iterating from the left direction but the right neighbour should also be checked. Run the same loop from right also and take the maximum of those two values. This should be your new candy assignment.

```
        n = int(input())
        candy = 1
        temp = int(input())
        list =[]
        rating =[]
        rating.append(temp)
        list.append(candy)
        for i in range(1,n):
            temp1 = int(input())
            rating.append(temp1)
            if (temp1>temp):
                candy = candy + 1        
            else:
                candy = 1
            list.append(candy)
            temp = temp1

        rating= rating[::-1]
        list = list[::-1]
        temp = rating[0]
        candies =list[0]
        for i in range(1,n):
            temp1 = rating[i]
            if (temp1>temp):
                list[i]= max(list[i-1]+1,list[i])

            candies =candies+list[i]
            temp = temp1

        print candies
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Going from backward and then maximizing the value is the key idea. I was not at all thinking about that. New to DP.

Answer (score 1):

```
    n = input()
    a = [input() for _ in xrange(n)]
   //min. candies he has to give  
    candies = [1] * n

        for i in xrange(1, n):
            if a[i] > a[i-1]:
                candies[i] = candies[i-1] + 1

        for i in xrange(n-2, -1, -1):
            if a[i] > a[i+1]:
                candies[i] = max(candies[i], candies[i+1] + 1)

        print sum(candies)
```

That is how i did this, by giving one candy at starting to each child.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I got the idea where I did the mistake.